# Submenu appears when the website reloading

Tags: html, css, wordpress, web, submenu

When i reload the [website](http://www.speckwords.com/spyrit/), submenu appears and when website is fully loaded, it disappears. Have a look http://www.speckwords.com/spyrit/

Thank you in advance

[image]

Comment: I suggest you set `display:none` to the dropdown in your CSS from the very beginning. At the moment it looks like `.sub-menu` is visible until it's altered by Javascript. Is that right? If so, it will be visible until your styles and scripts are loaded and your site is repainted.

Comment: That being said, you should include some more detail in your question, such as the markup, styles and scripts affecting your menu. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add to your css default style display: none;

`.menuzord-menu ul.dropdown, .menuzord-menu ul.dropdown li ul.dropdown, .menuzord-menu ul.sub-menu{
    display: none;
}`

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work... And even if it worked, there wouldn't be dropdown at all

Comment: Ok. All is clear. add this css. First your sub-menu class is diffrent before JS altering it. `.menuzord-menu ul.dropdown, .menuzord-menu ul.dropdown li ul.dropdown, .menuzord-menu ul.sub-menu{
    display: none;
}`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the files aren't loading in the correct order. I think it might be because wp-custom-css is being called after the javascript file for the menuzord plugin. Are you using a plugin for wp-custom-css or is it your own code?